# Promotion/raise during coronavirus pandemic

Tags: promotion, raise, covid-19

I am a high-performing engineer with a large embedded software business (hundreds developers, thousands of employees). My manager has told me as such, and I am known throughout the organization as a get-things-done employee. I've spoken with my manager about an upcoming promotion to a senior engineering position, which was originally projected to occur in Feburary or March.

Just before the pandemic started, he told me it would happen in April or May. Now I am concerned that it may not happen until much later in the year, with the CEO talking about "potential near-term cost-saving measures".

I have been performing senior engineer level work even according to the internal company performance metrics, so I want to ask for a promotion and raise as soon as possible. Is it unreasonable to expect such a change in compensation at this time? I don't mean to be insensitive to the economic position many others less fortunate than me find themselves in, but if I had been promoted back in Feburary when this happened then this wouldn't even be a question.

I am asking what the right way to approach my manager is about this. These are my thoughts so far:

- I have been performing at a senior engineer level for the past ~6 months at least.
- I am due for a promotion to that level *now*, and do not want to wait another 6 months for the compensation and career advancement.
- I feel that it is not right that the company should continue to benefit from my advanced skills but not be willing to compensate me for it until some unknown time in the future. If this were a small company struggling to get by at this time I would be more sympathetic, but this is not a small company at all.

I would prefer to fight for this promotion on the same schedule. Should I settle for a promise in writing for it in ~3 months? Or just let it go?

Comment: Have you weighted the pros and cons of this and found an answer?

Comment: I'm doing that now, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, the pros and cons can only be truly weighted by you, as it is your life and career.

Comment: With respect, one of the hallmarks of senior-level engineers is systems thinking ability. Your company is a large complex system that's subject to novel stressors right now. If you add the stressor of a deadline for a promotion, will it strengthen or weaken that system? What moves can you, personally, make to strengthen that system and make it more resilient?

Comment: You will appear to be totally self-centered and uninterested in anything but yourself. That would mark you out for rapid promotion in some companies, in others it will harm you. Which organizational culture are you in? If you don’t know then finding out is vital if you intend to stay there.

Answer (score 13):

If not for the COVID-19 pandemic I'd tell you to deal with this now.

BUT, we are dealing with the COVID-19 pandemic...on a global scale. The near future is uncertain for individuals AND for businesses. If it were me, I'd table this until we're closer to the other side of this, and when things are clearer from both a personal and a business perspective. For all you know, you may not even have this job in 3-6 months. Don't add undue stress to yourself, your manager, or your employer. I hate to sound pat, but those of us who are still employed really should be grateful that we are. My advice; Chill out, do the best you can, and wait until things are moving back toward some sense of normalcy, then re-evaluate. If you're still employed in 3-6 months, and if things have returned to normal (or semi-normal), then broach the subject with your manager.

Comment: This is comprehensive and relevant. Plus 1.

Answer (score 2):

Let me ask you another question: If you don't get the promotion *now*, what would you do? Would you really in an in an economically uncertain time leave your job or switch positions inside the company? since, if not, your boss may know this, and he/she may be less inclined to give this to you *now*. Moreover, even if you get it *now*, the fact that in a time when it's not excluded that co-workers will be let go, asked for it, will be remembered.